# How to select the last item in a pivot field using Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I have a pivot table having Pivot field "Date/Time" . I need a macro which selects the last item of the field. 
I tried the following code but is not working

```
Sub Test()

Dim i As Long

i = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date/Time").PivotItems.Count
With ActiveSheet
  .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date/Time").PivotItems(i).Visible=True
End With

End Sub
```

Please help me out. I just can't find my mistake.

Comment: `select` is never a great choice. What you can do is navigate to the field `Date/Time` then to the last row of that field/column.

Comment: Aren't these indexes 0-based ? You would need `i - 1`. Also, what does "does not work" mean to you ? Does it show an error message, does it just not do anything ?

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur I tried with i-1 too. It just not do anything.

Comment: @bonCodigo - As I am a beginner I don't know how to navigate. It would be great if you could explain.

Comment: @ankitagrawal I noticed couple of things: Assuming you have 3 fields in the pivot table. Name, Date Time, Location. Data is the sum of the projects done by each person on the given date in a Location. Now pivot table fields are set to sort manually by default. When you try to sort it by Date Time, the drop down of the Date Time sorts. However the all items across the table will still be shown by Asceding order of the Name field. I flip Name field to right and Date Time field to left, then it works and managed to pick the last item of Date Time. But this not the best solution - never.

Comment: I just want the Date/Time to get filtered.

Comment: @ankitagrawal try the sorting on 'Date/Time' column and pick the last item.

Answer (score 0):

This is no an elegant answer. Not something I could say that I am fully convinced. Since you said you just need to filter `Date/Time`, please try this out and comment.

```
Sub somePivot()
Dim n As Long

With Worksheets(2)
    n = .PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Date/Time").PivotItems.Count
    MsgBox n
    .PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Date/Time").AutoSort xlAscending, "Date/Time"
    MsgBox .PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Date/Time").PivotItems(n).Value
End With

End Sub
```